# foreach statement cannot operate

Tags: c#, xamarin, odata

I want to test odata with nortwind service in Xamarin. I have a click button which calls oDataClient.

I would like to implement the following scenerio: When I get the data, then I would like to display them on the console. However, it gives the following highlighted error.

[image]

I have made a research on it, and it says I should add `await` operator in front of client, then it gives me another error and ask me to use `Task` in the method. Then when I add it, it gives me another error. I would like to know ultimate solution rather then hanging there forever.

[image]

Comment: Well, what's unclear? You cannot execute `foreach` on a [`Task<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321424%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), only on [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9eekhta0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). By the way, it would be helpful if you could add the full error text of the error message into your question. It is visible in the screenshot, but not visible to full text search.

Comment: Did you mean `packages.Result`?

Comment: Please paste the exact full text of *all* of your errors into the question.

Comment: FWIW, I don't even attempt to answer questions where the error message is presented as a screenshot. Generally there isn't enough fidelity to read the error for my tired old eyes, plus I can't cut-and-paste from the post into a search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to enumerate over the results of the Task, not the Task itself

```
foreach(var package in packages.Result) {
...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason. I am testing it now. It sounds me right direction. let me quick test.

Comment: Hi Jason, I have run the code, it does not give me that error anymore, but even though I put a debug point at the foreach, it does not show me anything on the console, nothing happens. Quick note: I have changed the `Console.WriteLine(["ContactName"])`. By the way I have marked your answer.

Comment: From the error you posted, it looks like the Task contains an IEnumerable which contains a Dictionary - you may need to drill deeper in your data to find your actual results, or restructure your query to produce a flatter result set to iterate over.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to await the "FindEntriesAsync()" method...

Right now you are trying to iterate on the task, rather than result of the task...

Try this:

```
 var packages = await client.For("Customers")Top(2).FindEntriesAsync();
```

Comment: I have upvoted your answer as an alternative approach and for your effort.